# Importing a column into marketing cloud DE as add value to a column

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a DE in marketing cloud as an example below :

| Name | Age | Text_to_add |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 |  |
| B | 12 |  |
| C | 14 |  |

Now I have a file with `Text_to_add` as a column and three rows to be added. They are random and don't have any relation to DE above.
So, is there a way I can add the column to the above DE without any primary keys.

Comment: You cannot update the existing rows, WITHOUT PrimaryKey, using SQL. As there is NO PrimaryKey, even you will NOT able to edit Individual rows using Contact Builder as well :-|... FYI https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293657/updating-a-de-with-no-primary-keys

Comment: You can use SSJS to update a record in a DE without a PK, as described here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/299154/36623

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do in case you already have some records in the DE, but they don't have a primary key, would be to export the data into a cvs file, add the random data inside the csv file and re-import it to your DE to overwrite the existing records.

References:

[Export a Marketing Cloud Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_export_de.htm&type=5&language=en_US)

[Import into a Marketing Cloud Data Extension](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_import_into_de.htm&type=5)